# Erro ao tentar trocar icone JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Estou usando o NetBeans, porém quero alterar o ícone padrão da minha aplicação. Mas, me deparei com este erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

/**
 *
 * @author renato.lazaro
 */
public class IconJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form IconJFrame
     */
    public IconJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setIcon();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IconJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IconJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IconJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IconJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new IconJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setIcon() {
        setIconImage ( Toolkit . getDefaultToolkit (). getImage ( getClass (). getResource ( "iconframe.png" )));

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Outro erro que ocorreu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basta importar a classe, não!?

Comment: Importei para java awt Toolkit, porém a Aplicação retorna com erro.                 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Então o problema não é mais o da pergunta, provavelmente o resource informado no código está indo nulo, adicione o código aqui pra gente poder analisar.

Comment: Eu usei como referencia o exemplo do vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40ikcEonWng    Porém, retorna com erro, se alguém tiver outra solução e que possa estar ajudando.

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta, e um printscreen da hierarquia dos pacotes do seu projeto, onde a imagem do icone se encontra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome do seu arquivo está errado no código. No print, o arquivo está nomeado no pacote como *iconframe.png.PNG*, e no código está *iconframe.png*. Renomeie seu arquivo corretamente para *iconframe.png*(mais recomendado a se fazer), ou altere o código para:

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("iconframe.png.PNG")));
```

Comment: diegofm!  Funcionou perfeitamente, me atentei nas coisas mais complexas, mas deixei de lado uma coisa simples que fez total diferença na execução da aplicação.